# Python classes in seperate files AttributeError

Tags: python, class

So, I'm making a vulnerable site checker and I'm doing this using classes. I have one class for fixing the proxies and one for checking. Now I''m done with the proxy class and I started with the check file but I'm getting an error.

## proxy.py

```
class proxy:

def __init__(self):
    self.hdr = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}

def getrandproxy(self):
    proxies = []
    r = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html", headers=self.hdr)
    soup = BS(r.text, "lxml")
    container = soup.find("body").section.div.find('div', ['table-responsive']).table.tbody #path from body to proxy table, since parsing directly to it doesn't work
    for tr in container.find_all("tr"):
        ip = tr.td.text
        port = tr.td.next_sibling.text
        anonimity = tr.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
        https = tr.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
        if https == "yes" and anonimity == "anonymous" or anonimity == "elite proxy":
            server = ip + ":" + port
            proxies.append(server)
    return proxies
```

## injection.py

```
import requests, proxy
abc = proxy.getrandproxy()
print(abc)
```

I've tried to print the module on its own, and it worked. I just can't seem to figure out why there's an error. There's some code I cut out from proxy.py because else it would be very long. Tell me if you need all code. By the way the code I cut out isn't necessery, it's just some code with other functions.

## error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "injection.py", line 2, in <module> abc = proxy.getrandproxy()
AttributeError: module 'proxy' has no attribute 'getrandproxy'
```

Comment: If you fix the indentation of the first file, you may have an easier time. Otherwise you have a syntax error

Comment: It seems like you don't actually intend to write a class. Just remove the `class proxy:` line and all occurrences of `self`.

Comment: If this class actually has a reason to be a class (that is, its methods have some use for that `self` parameter), then you can’t use it without creating an instance: `myproxy = proxy.proxy()`. And then you can call methods on that instance, like `myproxy.getrandproxy()`.

Comment: That being said, it’s hard to understand what that class is supposed to represent. It’s called `proxy`, but the only thing it does is hold a header you never use and a method to get a random proxy. Except that method doesn’t even return a random proxy, it returns a list of proxy servers. So, all of the names are misleading, making it very hard to understand what the intended design is, making it even harder to tell you how to fix it to match that design.

Comment: @abarnert, the solution you gave me works and thnx for that. Sorry for my messy code but as I said that isn't my only function in my class, and I'm new with using classes so I'm trying to practise. I'm updating my code now, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, proxy
abc = proxy.proxy().getrandproxy()
print(abc)
```

You have a module named `proxy`, and inside that module is a class called `proxy`

Comment: Or `from proxy import proxy`

Comment: It gave me this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "injection.py", line 3, in <module>
    abc = proxy.getrandproxy()
TypeError: getrandproxy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: This still doesn’t make any sense, and still won’t work, because `proxy.proxy` is a class, and `getrandproxy` is an instance method.